# Can we store entire fact table in Rocksdb store of Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Since rocksdb is a persistent store. Is it a good practice to store entire fact table in rocksdb so that kafka streams can access it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it depends, but basically yes, you can do this. Kafka Streams uses RocksDB because it uses local disk and thus the state that the streaming application can handle is not limited to main-memory.

Comment: Basically, this thought arose because I was thinking of doing a streaming star schema join. Where all dimension tables can be persisted in rocksdb and `facts` can keep flowing in a stream and can be joined with dimension tables, creating a denormalised dataset.